# angular typescript ts(7053) error when trying to add search logic for an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Trying out TypeScript for a Angular project and I'm stuck on this error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Post'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Post'.ts(7053)
There is my code.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MultByPipe } from './pipes/mult-by.pipe';
import { ExMarksPipe } from './pipes/ex-marks.pipe';
import { FilterPipePipe } from './pipes/filter-pipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MultByPipe,
    ExMarksPipe,
    FilterPipePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../app.component';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(posts: Post[], search: string, field: string = 'title'): Post[] {
    if(!search.trim()){
      return posts
    }

    return posts.filter(post => {
      return post[field].toLowerCase.includes(search.toLowerCase())
    })
  }

}
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface Post {
  title: string 
  text: string 
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  search = ''
  searchField = 'title'
  
  posts: Post[] = [
    {title:  'Beer', text:  'Самое лучшее пиво в мире'},
    {title:  'Bread', text:   'The best bread in th world'},
    {title:  'JavaScript', text:  'The best language in the world'},

  ] 
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Angular pipes</h1>

  <button class="btn" (click)="searchField = 'title'">Title</button>
  <button class="btn" (click)="searchField = 'text'">Text</button>

 
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search">

  <div
    *ngFor="let post of posts | filterPipe:search:searchField"
   class="card"
  >
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ post.text }}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have an error in a pipe. Can anyone help me to understand what is the reason of it?

Comment: Noone of answers didn't help me. I have app component and pipe. Where i should to add part of code which i saw in example? i tryed in both files, but error didn't disapear